# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-3.x

When I tried save parsed data into a CSV file, I am getting the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in 
>   position 29: ordinal not in range(128)

I tried to use the command `from __future__ import unicode_literals` in the first line of my script, and used the following code to convert my integers and strings to byte strings:

```
self.writer.writerow([unicode(s).encode("utf-8") for s in row])
```

```
for article in Soup.find_all('article'):
    csv_writer.writerow([unicode(article).encode("utf-8") for article in Soup.find_all('article')])
    csv_writer.writerow([headline,paragraph,yt_link])
```

Error Message:

```
csv_writer.writerow([headline,paragraph,yt_link])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the script in python 3.6 then i got the expected output without any issue,earlier i tried to run the same script in python 3.7 at that time i got the above error